# Parsing Div with javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, jquery-selectors

I have a div 'rank', which contains another div 'line' which himself contains two div 'name' and 'value'. I want retrieve the 3 first name and value with Javascript and jQuery using a hash, but have no clue of how should I do. I'm thinking of using a loop and destroying the other divs when the 3 first line have been checked, but I don't know what do do after, and this solution is not very productive...

```
<div id='rank'>
<div class="line"><div class="name">1.&nbspmanone</div><div class="value">35</div></div>    
<div class="line"><div class="name">2.&nbspmantwo</div><div class="value">32</div></div>
<div class="line"><div class="name">3.&nbspmanthree</div><div class="value">30</div></div>
<div class="line"><div class="name">4.&nbspmanfour</div><div class="value">29</div>
</div><div class="line"><div class="name">5.&nbspmanfive</div><div class="value">25</div></div>
<div class="line"><div class="name">6.&nbspmansix</div><div class="value">24</div></div><div class="line"><div class="name">7.&nbspmanseven</div><div class="value">21</div></div><div class="line"><div class="name">8.&nbspmannine</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there are not all divs with class="name" inside div class.line

Comment: If it is the case, it's my fault, this is just a brief example to show my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use jQuery to find the first three lines, then build a javascript Object (a hash) of the text of the name and value divs:

```
$('#getTopThree').on('click', function(e) {
    var result = {}; //name and value will be placed in this object

    $('#rank .line:lt(3)').each(function() { //for each of the first three line divs
        var that = $(this);
        result[that.find('.name').text()] = that.find('.value').text(); //add name and value to result object
    });

    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result)); //print result for debugging
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2TpkL/)**

Comment: @sidney Great! Glad to help! Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer so other people visiting the question will be able to find the solution :)

Comment: However I don't know some stuff in your code...
-> .line:lt(3) ; that = $his(); and result[that.find('.name').text()] = that.find('.value').text();
If I have understood, line:lt(3) is a loop to parse the first 3 Lines
var that= $this; instantiates a new hash?
and the next lane set in that variable the name and value right?



Sure, I'm accepting the answer lol but I can't Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to accept in less than 3 minutes ^^

Comment: @sidney `.line:lt(3)` finds the first 3 elements with the class line. You can read about the lt() pseudselector here: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/. var `that = $(this);` creates a new variable named `that` which refers to the jQuery wrapper around the current element. This is to save the work of creating that wrapper twice. I suggest you read some basic javascript tutorials to help you out understanding the syntax.

Comment: I got the right logic to do a lot of things in javascript, but not the mechanics to write simple code like yours. Thanks a lot, I will definitely look at it ~